# Connecting a PhilipsHue led output to a relay

Tags: operational-amplifier, voltage-divider, solid-state-relay

I followed an [Instructables](http://www.instructables.com/id/Control-ANY-Light-With-Philips-Hue/) tutorial to get some understanding of what pins can be used from the Hue light bulb.

[image]

Out of all the "exposed" pins, I focused on

```
TP1 - Ground  
TP6 - LED output
```

(basically the top-left connector pins)

So my end-game is to have a relay controlled by the Hue app and turn on/off a 220VAC circuit (low power consumption, so a 10A/250V solid state relay like the one mentioned in the tutorial is just fine: `Fotek SSR-40 DA-H`)

[image]

But when measuring `TP6`, i found that it outputs `9VDC` when the LEDs are off and a maximum of `57.7VDC` when the LEDs are at 100%.

This is probably because i'm using newer bulbs than the ones used in the tutorial (i also didn't have the big black rubbery insulation on the circuit board)

I figured that the next steps would be

1. offset the output voltage so instead of 9-57.7 i would get 0-48.8 (by using an OpAmp)
2. use a voltage divider to get a 0-12 VDC output (so like a 1/4 divider)

Is this the right way to go? If yes, can you recommend an OpAmp that would do the job and some resistor characteristics i should consider (i'm mainly concerned about heating)?

Comment: Those Instructables articles are usually long and drawn out so not many of us will read it to find out how its supposed to work. Post the schematic or whatever's relevant into your question.

Comment: @Transistor Thanks for the feedback. I updated the post

Comment: That Fotek SSR may be a fake. See [UL.com notice](https://www.ul.com/newsroom/publicnotices/ul-warns-of-solid-state-relay-with-counterfeit-ul-recognition-mark-release-13pn-52/).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[image: schematic]

<sup>[simulate this circuit](/plugins/schematics?image=http%3a%2f%2fi.stack.imgur.com%2fG8wSE.png) – Schematic created using [CircuitLab](https://www.circuitlab.com/)</sup>

From the information you have provided a Zener diode would suffice. It won't conduct until the voltage exceeds the breakdown voltage. I'm suggesting a 15 V type to give a bit of margin since you have plenty of "headroom".

Power dissipation will be \$ V_Z \times I_{IN} \$ so do your calcultations!

Comment: woow! the zener diode totally slipped my mind! Thanks for the heads-up